# Make complex apps using p2p connections

Tags: javascript, database, webrtc, p2p, peerjs

in the last days I seen a technology called WebRTC that permit directly in Javascript to make p2p connections. What I've said to myself is: can i make complex web apps, like forums or social networks, that actually need databases to work fine, with WebRTC and p2p connection? Can someone tell me if is it possible and how it can be do this.

Comment: I don't see why it shouldn't be possible, but your question is too broad for Stack Overflow, so I've voted to close it. If you're interested in building apps with P2P, perhaps take a look at this project: https://beakerbrowser.com/

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can do it, any project complexity can be implemented using WebRTC API

WebRTC is a kind of standard now for audio/video p2p communication at this moment, so almost any projects that have audio/video calls use WebRTC API - at browser side, and also at iOS/Android

Here is an [open source example of 1-1 and group video chat](https://github.com/ConnectyCube/connectycube-js-samples/tree/master/sample-videochat-browser) app, which [uses WebRTC API](https://developers.connectycube.com/js/videocalling) broadly